# How can I interact with smart contract created from Marlowe in the testnet/mainnet?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, mainnet, marlowe, marlowe-pioneer-program

I create a smart contract with Marlowe from https://play.marlowe-finance.io

I now want to deploy the contract in the preview testnet and later mainnet. I imagine it must be somehow converted into plutus script. And then use the plutus script to create transaction via cardano-cli.

Is there a way to convert Marlowe into plutus script?
If not, how can I interact with smart contract created from Marlowe in the testnet/mainnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four methods for running Marlowe on the blockchain, in increasing order of difficulty:

1. *If you want to run your contract at the command line using `marlowe-cli`,* install [`marlowe-cli`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/blob/main/marlowe-cli/ReadMe.md#installation) and follow the instructions [in the tutorial for running contracts with `marlowe-cli`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/blob/main/marlowe-cli/lectures/04-marlowe-cli-concrete.md). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x0GbvCw-61e9VfRafBT1JSw) is a video lecture that provides an overview of `marlowe-cli`.
2. *If you want to run your contract in a Jupyter notebook,* then use git to clone [github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano), run `nix develop --command jupyter-lab` from the `marlowe-cli/` folder, open the notebook [marlowe-cli/lectures/04-marlowe-cli-concrete.ipynb](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/blob/main/marlowe-cli/lectures/04-marlowe-cli-concrete.ipynb), and follow the instructions. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmF7dIKmJMo&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x0GbvCw-61e9VfRafBT1JSw&index=4) is a video lecture of running a contract from within a Jupyter notebook.
3. *If you want to run your contract from the command-line using the Marlowe Runtime backend,* then follow the [tutorial for Marlowe Runtime](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/blob/main/marlowe-runtime/doc/tutorial.ipynb). [Here](https://youtu.be/WlsX9GhpKu8) is a video demonstration.
4. *If you want to run your contract using Marlowe Lambda,* follow [the example for using Marlowe Lambda from the command line](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-lambda/blob/main/examples/zcb.ipynb) or study [the example web application for Marlowe Lambda](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-lambda/tree/main/web). [Here](https://youtu.be/huXbRyrmW60) is video of a command-line example and [here](https://youtu.be/o5m_y5l_i_g) is a video of a web app example.

> Is there a way to convert Marlowe into plutus script? If not, how can I interact with smart contract created from Marlowe in the testnet/mainnet?

Marlowe contracts are run as `datum` in the Marlowe validator, which is a Plutus script that can run any Marlowe contract. There is no need (or possibility) of converting a Marlowe contract directly to Plutus.

Also, `mainnet` is disabled in the Marlowe tools, but you can alter the source code [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/search?q=guardMainnet) and/or [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano/blob/3ffdbbd0b63b36e7a1277d53f07d3c4f0138dcf0/marlowe-runtime/src/Language/Marlowe/Runtime/Transaction/Server.hs#L177-L178) to enable `mainnet` if you want to run there. Note that Marlowe's audit is not complete, so it is not advisable to run on `mainnet`.

Comment: Damn! you're good

Comment: Just realize you're the guy in the video, the creator himself. Good job, man.

Comment: Here are some more example Marlowe contracts: https://github.com/input-output-hk/real-world-marlowe#gallery-of-marlowe-contracts-on-cardano-mainnet.